# form fields count and names to PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

I have form with changable content of textareas, from 1 to 5, each time with different names. I cannot modify the form itself.

how can i get number of textareas in form and names of them (it would be the best if i could do it clean in php without javascript).

the form is using `method="POST"` and `PHP version is 5.2+`

EDIT: i forgot to tell you that i have only textareas in form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of :

```
$count=0;
$formElements=array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    $count++;
    $formElements[]=$key;
}

echo "The form as $count elements.";
var_dump($formElements);
```

If you want the values of the post you could make a two dimensional array like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    $count++;
    $formElements[]=array($key => $val);
}
```

Comment: As long as you have other inputs in the form, you would have to prefix textareas' names and filter those in the iteration.

Comment: @MikulasDite True, but I don't think there is any way to determine via PHP the *type* of form element being submitted.

Comment: great i will try that in a moment. thank you very much. I didnt thought that i can use only _post without attribute. Unfortunetly i have to do even three dimensional(i need to break it in the lines) so it will be the slowest programm ever done:)

Answer (score 0):

if you post form to php script, `$_POST` variable is array. then you can use something like this:

`foreach($_POST as $v){}` to get every field.